# Why is a parameter parsed as a bool?

Tags: docopt

I usually use [`docopt`](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) to handle the command line parameters but I now have a case where the parameters is parsed unexpectedly (it must be a silly mistake of mine as it always works great)

```
"""
API to do something

Usage:
    api.py [options]

Options:
    --port PORT     port to listen on   [default: 64645]
    --url   URL     elasticsearch address   [default: http://elk.example.com:9200]
"""
```

This is parsed via a `conf = docopt.docopt(__doc__)` call after which I have `conf` set to

```
{
    '--port': '64645',
    '--url': False
}
```

The `--url` part is not correct but I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because there are too many spaces between `--url` and `URL`, try:

```
"""
API to do something

Usage:
    api.py [options]

Options:
    --port PORT     port to listen on   [default: 64645]
    --url URL       elasticsearch address   [default: http://elk.example.com:9200]
"""
```

Comment: looks like a bug to me

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, as it is mentioned in the documentation: "Use two spaces to separate options with their informal description."

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [official documentation](http://docopt.org):

> To specify that an option has an argument, put a word describing that argument after **one space** or "=" sign.
>
> Use **two spaces** to separate options with their informal description.